# BootGrid bug: GET method not working

Tags: rest, querystringparameter, jquery-bootgrid

If I use the `method: "GET"` I get an `HTTP 405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED`
because the current=1&rowCount=20 is attempted to be sent in the data instead of on the queryString, which as far as I understand is not allowed for GET.

What can be done?

This question of course is about [JQuery.BootGrid](http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/Documentation)

Comment: With the new bootgrid 1.1.0 you can use the new requestHandler and set it to send whatever data is wished  

I'm not sure though that it know how to convert this to querystring parameters. 

JQuery .ajax function does that when you set the 'data' parameter...

Comment: I opened an issue on the bootgrid issues board: 

https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-bootgrid/issues/222